# How do I create a dropdown inside a vue <b-table that will save selected item by row of table

Tags: vue.js

```
<b-row v-if="userIdArr.length >0 && incidentIdArr.length ===0" class="mt-5">
    <b-col md="10" offset-md="1">
        <b-table overflow="auto" hover border :items="userIdArr" :fields="userArrTblfields">
          <template slot="serialDropdown" slot-scope="row">
             <b-form-select v-model="selectedSerial" :options="serialOptions"></b-form-select>
         </template> 
     </b-table>
  </b-col>
```

now down in my <script:

```
                userIdArr: [],
                userArrTblfields: [
                    { key: 'id', label: 'id', class: 'text-center' },
                    { key: 'firstname', sortable: true, class: 'text-center' },
                    { key: 'lastname', sortable: true, class: 'text-center' },
                    { key: 'employeeID', sortable: true, class: 'text-center' },
                    { key: 'serialDropdown', sortable: true, class: 'text-center' }
                    ],
                selectedUser: null,
                selectedSerial: [], 
                serialOptions: [
                    { value: 'J00001', text: 'J00001'},
                    { value: 'J00002', text: 'J00002'},
                    { value: 'J00003', text: 'J00003'},
                    { value: 'J00004', text: 'J00004'},
                    { value: 'J00005', text: 'J00005'}
                ],
```

The dropdown appears however it shows the same values for all table rows and the select of the dropdown is duplicated for each row??? How can I separate out the selected values and keep the dropdowns separate per table row?

Comment: There's not enough context to reproduce the problem. Can you share a link to a reproduction?

Comment: I solved the problem by adding row.selectedSerial StackOverflow isn't letting me answer my own question. I've got no answers but they are censoring me already